# Single WMS pgRouting Layer from Array of Lat Longs

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers, pgrouting

I am using the following loop for displaying the a bus route. 'stopLonLat' is a JavaScript object with all the latitude and longitude values of various bus stops. Since I am not looking for shortest path between origin and destination, I consider each bus stops, find route between them and draw the route in the loop.

```
     var startLon,startLat,destLon,destLat,viewparams,params;

        for(var i=0;i<stopLonLat.length-1;i=i+1) {

                 startLon= 'x1:' + stopLonLat[i].Longitude; 
                 startLat= 'y1:' + stopLonLat[i].Latitude;

                 destLon='x2:' + stopLonLat[i+1].Longitude;
                 destLat='y2:' + stopLonLat[i+1].Latitude;
                 viewparams = [
                  startLon,startLat,
                  destLon,destLat
                ];
                params = {
                      LAYERS: 'pgrouting:pgrouting2',
                      FORMAT: 'image/png',
                      viewparams:viewparams.join(';')
                };
                //params.viewparams = viewparams.join(';');
                routeLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
                  source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/pgrouting/wms',
                    params: params
                  })
                });   

                me.getOMap().addLayer(routeLayer);
        }
```

Now there are two problems I am facing.

1. Since there will be a lot of number of bus stops in a route of 200km to 700 km, there will be that much 'routeLayer' will be created. Which makes map rendering extensively slow.
2. I cannot remove the layer 'routeLayer'

I don't know whether the procedure I'm following is correct.